# Renaming files on external SD card

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

I have a number of folders on an external SD card (note: **Not** "external storage" as Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory()) and i wish to rename them from inside my app. In my mainfest xml file I have added both the "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permissions. I have tried to use file.renameTo(), but it doesn't appear to work on external SD cards. Code like:

```
File old = new File("/storage/MicroSD/folder_old")  
File new = new File("/storage/MicroSD/folder_new")  
old.renameTo(new);
```

**does not work** on the external sd card (works fine if I use /storage/emulated/0/... instead). Reading through some similar questions, it looked like there was no way to write to the external SD card outside of your app's app-specific folder. However, an app like amaze can rename files/folders on  my external sd card no problem so there has to be some way to do it.

Comment: I thought you can't use `new` as variable name in Java...

Comment: what do you mean with "doesn not work"? It crashes? Your files aren't renamed?

Comment: Amaze is open source. Go look and see what they do. My guess is that they are using the Storage Access Framework and `DocumentFile`.

Comment: Which Androd version are you talking about? From Android 4.4 apps are not allowed to write on removable micro SD card anymore. Only in one app specific directory. Is `/storage/MicroSD` the path to your card?

Comment: @CommonsWare... now that i see you here... What happened to Samba client app for Android? It's not in the store anymore. Looks like a nice feature but now its missing: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/07/06/samba-uri.html Can you update that post?

Comment: @CommonsWare. I was wrong i think.  Now that i tried that link from a DeskTop browser i got "Sorry! This content is not available in your country yet.
We're working to bring the content you love to more countries as quickly as possible.
Please check back again soon.". But then i hope it comes soon.

Comment: @greenapps: I get that same message. I am not completely clear what is going on there.